# Bootstrap Drop Down List Aligning Horizontal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three drop down list which includes Days Months and Years for getting birthday from user.
I don't want to put them in a table. I'm trying to work with just Div elements for efficiency.

How can i fix them according to the above textbox ?

The following code is for my registration form

```html
        <div class="text-center">
            or
        </div>             

            <label>Firstname</label>
            <div>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">                  
            </div>

            <label>Lastname</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname">  
            </div>

            <label>Email</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">  
            </div>

            <label>Password</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">  
            </div>

            <label>Gender</label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>              
                </select>
            </div><br />

           <div class="text-center">
                <label>Birthday</label>
                <div class="form-inline" role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Day">                           
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>            
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Month">                           
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">February</option>             
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="input-group">
                            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Year">                           
                            <option value="1950">1950</option>
                            <option value="1951">1951</option>              
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: replicate your problem in a bootply and post it in your question; http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: I did it as you described.

Comment: Alright, now what do you mean by fix them according to the 'above textbox'

Comment: I meaned that the birthday's inputs are aligned according to the above inputs.It doesn't seem good as you see

Comment: Did i tell problem clearly ?